# Google lens serpapi is giving me an abortsignal error. The code was the same the other day and now this error popped up?

Tags: javascript, node.js, serpapi

My nodejs script was working perfectly fine the other day and now I'm getting this abort signal error below. The code is literally copied verbatim from the serpapi site. I had my own code that's slightly different but I get the same error even when just using the site's sample code. https://serpapi.com/google-lens-api. It seems to be a local issue because when I ran it standalone on Replit it seemed to be fine. My package json is below as well.

```
import { getJson } from "serpapi";

const params = {
  url: "https://i.imgur.com/HBrB8p0.png",
  api_key: "{xxx}"
};

// Show result as JSON
const response = await getJson("google_lens", params);
console.log(response["visual_matches"]);
```

```
"name": "cheerio",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/vision": "^3.1.1",
    "axios": "^1.3.2",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.12",
    "jimp": "^0.22.4",
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.0",
    "openai": "^3.1.0",
    "serpapi": "^1.1.0"
```

signal: AbortSignal.timeout(timeout),
^
ReferenceError: AbortSignal is not defined

Answer (score 1):

I think something wrong with your node environment. Try to remove your `node_modules` directory, install the latest [node LTS version](https://nodejs.org/en/), and then install your dependencies again.